# Rails simple_form association not saving to db

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, simple-form, has-and-belongs-to-many, whitelist

I have 2 models with a HABTM relationship: authors and publications.

Using simple_form, I was able to create a `add new publication` form that shows all of the possible authors as checkboxes. However, these associations are not saving to my db.

I know this is a params permit issue, but I'm not sure how to properly write it. Currently I have:

```
def publication_params
    params.require(:publication).permit(:publication_id, :name, :year_published, :month_published, :day_published, :citation, :source, :abstract)
end
```

How do I write this so that rails can allow the association from the authors table (which has only two columns-- `author_id` and `name`) to be saved too?

Answer (score 1):

Got it!

I had to add `accepts_nested_attributes_for :authors, :journals` into my publication model. Then in my publications_controller, I had to change my params to:

```
def publication_params
    params.require(:publication).permit(:publication_id, :name, :year_published, :month_published, :day_published, :citation, :source, :abstract, :author_ids => [], :journal_ids => [])
end
```

This allowed me to save new associations to my db, and it updated my join table correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Add `author_id` to the params:

```
def publication_params
    params.require(:publication).permit(:author_id, :publication_id, :name, :year_published, :month_published, :day_published, :citation, :source, :abstract)
end
```

Comment: can you post here the params received in the controller ?
You can install this gem https://github.com/pry/pry
And then add "binding.pry" at the beginning of your controller action and then see in the server's logs that you can evalutate the params

Comment: `def publication_params
    params.require(:publication).permit(:publication_id, :author_id, :name, :year_published, :month_published, :day_published, :citation, :source, :abstract,)
  end`

Comment: @League14 I meant the actual params, the ones received throught the request

Comment: Ok, I'm new to pry, and I _think_ I used it correctly. Please correct me if I'm wrong. Here is what my server says:

Comment: Started POST "/publications" for ::1 at 2017-08-07 16:27:40 -0400
Processing by PublicationsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"RVi95ns3ECRctfNprDS3gvBLAxt5VN5sn25FJCdbGuEmEJblYPw1eoEHu4GMzcm8gar2qnIZTjweUNzvqJok8Q==", "publication"=>{"name"=>"Default", "author_ids"=>["", "2", "3"], "journal_ids"=>["", "2"], "year_published"=>"2009", "month_published"=>"26", "day_published"=>"21", "citation"=>"test", "source"=>"test", "abstract"=>"test"}, "commit"=>"Create Publication"}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 3ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)